# gradle task assemble debug failed

Tags: flutter, dart

after updating plugins and android studio. i have to manually configured dart- sdk after every restart in android studio. and when i upgrade dart-sdk its showing this error=>

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:137: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
      return (List<String>) stream.readObject();
                                             ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    Object
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:182: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invoca
tion: constructor <init> in class ArrayList is applied to given types
          List<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>((Set) value);
                                   ^
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found: Set
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:182: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
          List<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>((Set) value);
                                                   ^
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found:    Set
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:182: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
          List<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>((Set) value);
                                   ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    ArrayList
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:26: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() i
n FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
                        ^
5 warnings
```

also its not showing suggestions in code. i spent almost whole day to solve this error please help. after this i never update again any plugin or my android studio .

Answer (score 4):

just add multiDexEnabled true in your build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

// add this line
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

In the same file add the multidex dependency inside

```
dependencies {
     // If you're project has androidx support then add this dependency
     implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

     // If you're project doesn't have androidx support then add this dependency
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

To know more about androidX migration [visit the documentation here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` commands. Inside Android Studio invalidate caches and restart (File -> Invalidate caches / restart).

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to Android X
And Override every Android library to AndroidX in the gradle file
that should do.